# Calculate $\lim _{x\to 0^+}\frac{\left(e^x-e^{-x}\right)}{\sin x}$

Tags: analysis

***How to find the this limit without using L'Hopital's Rule.

$\lim _{x\to 0^+}\frac{\left(e^x-e^{-x}\right)}{\sin x}$

Comment: use maclaurin series for $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- Use maclaurin series for $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$
- then apply $$\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\sin x}{x}=1$$

Comment: Thank you so much for hint I solved the question.

Comment: @BerkcanAytemur No problem when you ask problem write down your attempt

Comment: I don't get why in this kind of question  L'Hopital is forbidden and Taylor/MacLaurin expansion is allowed. L'Hopital is much simpler.

Comment: @Raffaele There are some courses at the end of the course instructures teach L'hospital  rule. I also  learn L'hospital after went to the university before I went to the university I used such a property even though I didn't know  what it was

Answer (score 1):

Two famous limits give it as$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x}{\sin x}\left(\frac{e^x-1}{x}+\frac{e^{-x}-1}{-x}\right)=1(1+1)=2.$$